# php number_format() where formating string is a variable

Tags: php

I get the following error when I try to use number format in php:

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

```
$number = 10345.34543;
$format = "0, ',', '.'";
echo number_format($number, $format);
```

I am almost positive it is because I'm holding the formating part in a string, but is there any way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: [Read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). The answers are there. You're completely misusing the function.

Answer (score 1):

The format you are trying to pass the arguments in is not possible. You are passing a string instead of an `int`.

The [expected parameters](http://www.php.net/number_format) are:

```
string number_format ( float $number , 
                       int $decimals = 0 , 
                       string $dec_point = '.' , 
                       string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

you will need to pass the arguments accordingly:

```
echo number_format($number, 0, ",", ".");
```

If you have a special reason to do this the way you show, you would have to use `eval()` which is highly discouraged, or maybe [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) but you would have to explain in detail first what you are trying to do.

Comment: My reason for doing this is that I'd like to store the format in the DB. $format is actually a string that I'm getting from my DB. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: @David I would either store the values separately, or use something like `sprintf()` which allows storing a `#.##` format pattern without the security implications