# trouble with calculating percentage using PHP

Tags: php

I wanted to calculate the percentage using `PHP`. I tried the code given below but its gives me the return value in float. i don't know much in `PHP` so please fix this code.

**current OUTPUT**

---

```
66.666666666667%
```

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
66.66%
```

---

```
 <?php 
    $up=4;
    $down:2;
    echo (($ups/($ups+$downs))*100).'%'; 
   ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php number\_format() where formating string is a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422761/php-number-format-where-formating-string-is-a-variable)

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna sure it is duplicate of that but i don't know about that function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `number_format()` to specify your decimals and separator.

```
     <?php 
        $up=4;
        $down:2;
        $num = (($ups/($ups+$downs))*100).'%'; 
        $formatted_num = number_format($num, 2, '.', '');
       echo $formatted_num;
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :
echo round(66.666666666667, 2); >> 66.66